# Create a new button with Js or php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css

I have a mini cart (drop down) on my WP site. I have styled the design for when there are products and when empty. I have used CSS pseudo before and after to add contents.

Possible to add a button with a link as well? I am trying to have a button when it is empty.

Following is my CSS and the Js code I tried, since I don't have access to the html.

```
.woocommerce-mini-cart__empty-message{
     padding-top: 30px;
     text-align:center;
     visibility:hidden;
     color: #5D5D5D;
     background-color:#F0EFEB;
     pointer-events: none;
}
 .woocommerce-mini-cart__empty-message::after{
     content: 'Lets start shopping!';
     visibility:visible;
     display:block;
     margin-top:2px!important;
     font-size:14px!important;
     line-height:20px!important;
     font-family:futura!important;
     pointer-events: none;
}
 .woocommerce-mini-cart__empty-message::before {
     content: url(http://naristore.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/shop- icon@2x.png) '\A \A YOUR BAG IS EMPTY';
     white-space: pre;
     visibility:visible;
     display:block;
     text-align:center;
     color:#5D5D5D!important;
     font-size:24px!important;
     line-height:26px!important;
     font-family:futura!important;
     letter-spacing:1px;
     pointer-events: none;
}


<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("<button>click</button").appendTo('.woocommerce-mini- cart__empty - message ');
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you are asking.. Are you just trying to add a button? If so use append, not appendTo.

```
<script>
$(document) .ready(function(){
      var element= "<button>click</button";

    $(".woocommerce-mini- 
cart__empty-message") .append(element)

});
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks, Yes I want to add a button and nothing happened with append either. I guess I am missing something

Answer (score 0):

Try using JavaScript instead of jquery.

---

```css
.btn-style {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 15px 24px;
  text-align: center;
  border: none;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #008CBA;
  margin: 2px 5px;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: .95em;
}
```

```html
const woocommerce = document.querySelector('.woocommerce-mini-cart__empty-message');
const btn = document.createElement('button');
btn.textContent = 'Empty';
btn.className = 'btn-style';
woocommerce.appendChild(btn);
```

Don't forget to select the added class btn-style & adding desired styles. I have added some basic css.